# Setting alpha value on grayscale image for pre-lollipop devices looks vastly different

Tags: android, imageview, grayscale, colormatrix

Having a bit of a problem on pre-Lollipop devices concerning setting grayscale on my imageviews.  Specifically, setting transparency after using this code to convert an imageview to greyscale:

```
public static void setGrayScale(ImageView view) {

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
    matrix.setSaturation(0);

    ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
    paint.setColorFilter(filter);

    view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, paint);
}
```

On 5.0+ devices, the image is converted to greyscale then the alpha value is applied, resulting in a nice looking image.

[image]

On pre 5.0 devices (specifically Nexus 4 with 4.2.2), it appears that the alpha value isn't being respected, and a darker grey appears instead.

[image]

Does anyone know why this behavior would be happening?  It's the same exact setAlpha value (0.6f).  I tried different methods of applying greyscale and also attempted to setAlpha before and after to no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cause is the implementation of ColorMatrixColorFilter class is changed from Lollipop as you can see in [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/graphics/ColorMatrixColorFilter.java/?v=diff&id2=4.4.4_r1).

Workaround for your problem is set different value for lollipop above in `values-v21` folder and pre-lollipop value inside `values`.

Comment: Good find.  If the implementation is different, how do I use the new implementation on pre-lollipop devices?  Setting the values in the values-v21 folder doesn't really describe my use case since it's being set programmatically.

Comment: @FrostRocket you can set the values in the values-v21 and get it using getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor); and then use it programatically

Comment: I know you can add the values, but the main issue is that the bitmap looks different.  Pre 5.0, the alpha value appears to be ignored.  After 5.0, it seems fine.  Adding a different alpha value for each OS via values isn't going to solve my problem.